# Is it better to insert data into cassandra without checking its existence first?

Tags: cassandra

Given the fact that you can't insert duplicates in Cassandra (if the keys are the same) and it simply overrides the existing data, if I have to insert a single row into the database that I don't actually know if it already exists, is it better to just write it anyway or should I check if it exists first and if it's not there, insert it?

The data at the end of the day will be the same but I was wondering if, performance wise, it was better to simply write the data without checking its existence or if it was faster to check it first and only insert if needed.

Imagine that my read replication factor is set to 2 and write is set to 3.

Does anyone know?

Many thanks,

**Update:**

A sample column family is this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notifications (
userid uuid,
deviceid uuid,
devicename text,
PRIMARY KEY(userid, deviceid)
);
```

The purpose of this column family is to capture the device id/names of the users which will be used when I'm sending them MQ notifications. Every time the user logs in, I have to make sure I capture the device id since that's what I use to notify them. As users can login from a host of devices, there can be multiple userid/deviceid pairs in my database per user but the userid/deviceid pair should be unique.

Comment: That depends on whether the given must be historized or update. Can you give some informations about your data structure and business rules ?

Comment: Your data structure look good. As you said, Cassandra overwrite data on existing PK it is better to write without checking data (unique database interaction -> better performence). Remember that Cassandra is more efficient on write.

Comment: @GuillaumeS Thanks. That's what I thought. Please mark your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: In theory you could use light-weight transactions to only insert the data if it doesn't exist (IF NOT EXISTS), but that will add some overhead.  I would say unless you would be writing this data incredibly frequently, writing repeatedly should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure look good. As you said, Cassandra overwrite data on existing PK it is better to write without checking data (unique database interaction -> better performence). Remember that Cassandra is more efficient on write.